Gradients of vertices on a grid

Say we have an irregular 2D grid, it can be viewed as a group of triangles composed, and we know the value of function v(x,y) on the plane at each vertex on the grid (The picture is just for displaying a grid and I don't use the Ansatz function here since it is not continuous).
so we can use the value of two neighboring vertex and their coordinates to approximate the gradient of the middle point on the corresponding edge
(let's say we use (V1-V2/x1-x2, V1-V2/y1-y2) to approximate the gradient of ((x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2))
But we're actually interested in the gradient of each vertex, any ideas? It seems using an interpolation function is inevitable right?

This post may be of interest
